# How to cache file downloads with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to download some files.

For each cell, I check if the file exists and is already stored in a directory, if not I download it.

But I also download files for the next couple of cells.

**What happens, if I am trying to download a file for an invisible cell ahead of time, but then the user scrolls to the cell and the file is not fully downloaded yet.**

Is there anyway to prevent it from downloading twice? 
**Is there anyway to know that the file is already getting downloaded?**

I am using AFNetworking.

Comment: I believe AFNetworking caches the results by URL. You can check if it is actually calling the network service again by using something like Charles. http://www.charlesproxy.com I use it for debugging all my network calls.

Comment: @Fogmeister it is true that `AFNetworking` use `NSURLCache`. But files bigger then 10% of the total cache size will not be cashed by `NSURLCache`.

Comment: The files range from 150KB - 250KB, are these too big for NSURLCache? @rckoenes

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do has a name and it's *caching*.

`AFNetworking` already implements it as per the [official FAQs](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ#does-afnetworking-have-any-caching-mechanisms-built-in)

> ## Does AFNetworking have any caching mechanisms built-in?
>
> `AFNetworking` takes advantage of the caching functionality already provided by `NSURLCache` and any of its subclasses. So long as your `NSURLRequest` objects have the correct cache policy, and your server response contains a valid Cache-Control header, responses will be **automatically cached** for subsequent requests.

Set up the cache as follows and you'll be ok

```
- (void)setupCache {
    NSURLCache *urlCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024*4 // 1MB mem cache
                                                         diskCapacity:1024*1024*5 // 5MB disk cache
                                                             diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:urlCache];
}
```

Then just perform requests normally and if the resource is in cache you'll get a cache hit and you won't be downloading it twice.

---

Note that if you have to support anything below `iOS5`, you have to use an alternative URL cache like [`SDURLCache`](https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache) and set it up like follows

```
- (void)setupCache {
    SDURLCache *urlCache = [[SDURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024   // 1MB mem cache
                                                         diskCapacity:1024*1024*5 // 5MB disk cache
                                                             diskPath:[SDURLCache defaultCachePath]];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:urlCache];
}
```

The reason is well explained in [this article](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5/), but it can be summarized by the following quote:

> Before iOS5, `NSURLCache` just saved requests to memory, even if the documentation said otherwise - the diskCapacity property was silently ignored

Comment: You could also use [`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the same way, there is not need fro an external library. Since iOS 5 `NSURLCache` will handle cache headers correctly. Just be aware that files lager then 10% of the total cache size will not be cached.`NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4*1024*1024 diskCapacity:20*1024*1024 diskPath:nil];` Then just set the shared cache: `[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];`

Comment: @rckoenes you're right about `NSURLCache`, do you have any reference about the 10% total cache size thing?

Comment: So do I just call `setupCache` from `viewDidLoad`, (if not where should I call this method from), and then AFNetworking will recognize it, and won't try to download it twice?

Comment: Oh, just saw the updated answer, so I guess AFNetworking does it for me (I am just using the standard AFNetworking methods, so I assume the caching policy is correct). Thanks, this answer was helpful!

Comment: @GanstaGraham, I usually call the setup code in the app delegate, at app launch.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella It's not really documented any where and might just be more then 5% actually. I've just been try out some cache size and say that some big files just are not cached.

Comment: @rckoenes ok, then I guess there's a performance reason behind it.